# A brief answer for the determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, symmetry

I am given the following matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{6 \times 6}$, where $a_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^{10} x_k^{i+j-2}$.

**Remark:** If $A=(a_{ij})_{10 \times 10}$ with the same $a_{ij}$ defined above, the answer is very classical, i.e., $\det(A)=\prod_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2$. But in my case the matrix size is smaller than 10, so I have no idea.

Clearly that $A$ is a real symmetric matrix consisting of power sum. I am wondering if there is a brief expression for $\det(A)$.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Let $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \ldots & 1 \\ x_1^1 & \ldots &x_{10}^1 \\ \vdots & \vdots& \vdots\\ x_1^5 & \ldots &x_{10}^5 \end{pmatrix}\\$.

Note that $A=BB^T$. Hence $\det A=\det(BB^T)$.

The last determinant can be computed using Cauchy-Binet formula.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM I tried this way before, but there seems still no brief expression for the result.